# Sort Json and Get Up down data from Current Postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I want sort the `json` object and then get Grade up down and down from current position.

I have following `json` object.

```
[
  {
    "Grade": "1+"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "1"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "1-"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "10"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "11"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "12"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "2+"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "2"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "2-"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "3+"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "3"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "3-"
  }
]
```

**Example 01:** 
suppose My current location is `1+`

- If i click on `down word` button then `1 minus` and get result `1`
- If i again click on `down word` button then `1 minus` and get result
  `1-`
- If i again click on `down word` button then `1 minus` and get result
  `2+`
- If i  click on `up word` button then `1 minus` and get result `1-`

**I tried**

```
var arr = [];

for(var jj in RatingGrade)
arr.push([jj, RatingGrade [jj]]);
console.log(RatingGrade);
var start = "1+";
var counter = 0;//work on up down button by increase and decrease
if( counter < 0 ){

  $('#gen_override_gradename').text(arr[i - (counter)].GradeNo);
  $('#pd_GradeName').text(arr[i - (counter)].GradeName);
  $('#gen_avg_pd').text(arr[i - (counter)].AveragePD);

     } else {
          if(counter == 0){
            $('#gen_override_gradename').text($('#rating_grade').text());
                               $('#pd_GradeName').text($('#base_pd_score').text());

                     } else {

                         $('#gen_override_gradename').text(arr[i - (1 + (counter))].GradeNo);
                         $('#pd_GradeName').text(arr[i - (1 + (counter))].GradeName);
                         $('#gen_avg_pd').text(arr[i - (1 + (counter))].AveragePD);
                     }

                }
```

but its working fine.

Comment: If it's working fine, what is the question? A live demo in jsfiddle.net or other code share site would be helpful if there is a problem

Comment: @charlietfl,My first question is how can i sort json ?Like i want [
  {
    "Grade": "1+"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "1"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "1-"
  },
 
  {
    "Grade": "2+"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "2"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "2-"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "3+"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "3"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "3-"
  }, {
    "Grade": "10"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "11"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "12"
  },
]

Comment: Can you give those objects another property like `order` that is numeric?

Comment: @charlietfl actually there grades and i want sort these by same order

Comment: Well you either have to parse those `+/-` in a sort function or simpler is add a numeric order property to sort by. Again a demo would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will sort your json:

```
json.sort(function (a, b) {
    return = a.id - b.id;
});
```

However, the `+` and `-` signs will need to be handled with additional logic as you're voiding out the "integer value" by including the symbol. Now it's a string and 1+ hold no value when you are trying to compare it to 1. Basically, parse out the symbols and throw them back in after the sorting is completed.

Comment: json.sort(function (a, b) {
    returna.id  =  b.id;
}); not working